# Displaying BSQ file in ArcGIS ESRI GRID format?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, esri-grid-format

I have a bsq file and I was able to produce the header from the metadata.

What steps do I take to display this BSQ file in ArcGIS ESRI GRID format?

Comment: What do you mean "display this BSQ file in ArcGIS ESRI GRID format"? Do you mean you want to _display_ the BSQ in ArcGIS ArcMap, i.e show it on the map? Or do you want to _convert_ the BSQ to an ESRI GRID format.

Answer (score 1):

BSQ (band sequential by pixel) [is an Esri raster type](http://webhelp.esri.com/arcgisdesktop/9.2/index.cfm?TopicName=BIL,_BIP,_and_BSQ_raster_files), if it's not displaying then perhaps you're missing the header file that goes with it.

To convert to an Esri GRID format use a tool like [CopyRaster](http://resources.arcgis.com/en/help/main/10.1/index.html#//001700000094000000) to copy it to a grid (just don't add an extension).

Esri GRID has *very* specific naming rules: Max length 13 characters, no spaces in path or GRID name... be careful where you put it and what you call it.

> It cannot be stored using spaces. 
>   It cannot start with a number. 
>   It cannot be longer than 13 characters (a multiband grid is allowed up to
>   9 characters).

From [Esri Grid Format in Esri Help](http://help.arcgis.com/en/arcgisdesktop/10.0/help/index.html#//009t0000000w000000).